# Is there a substitute for quote marks " and ' in Javascript document.write function

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if there is a way to write paragraphs containing both the double quotes and single quotes that can't pass on [ document.write(""); document.write('');] whichever I use. Is there some features that I'm not aware of? Please enlighten me

Thanks

Comment: On StackOverflow, when your question is answered and that answer solves your problem, you are required to **pick** that answer and mark it correct. You do that by clicking on the checkmark left of the answer that solved your problem best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use backticks ([template literals](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals)):

```
``
```

```js
document.write`<p class="my-class">'Hi', she said.</p>`;
```

Comment: I haven't realized that's possible until now. Thank you so much!